# How can i get image using preg_match_all

Tags: php, image, get

i need some help for get images. Im using preg_match_all function.

Source: `<img alt="test" title="test" src="/data/brands/test.png">`

how can i get full image url ?

And this is my code for text. I need add image here.

```
<?
$link = 'link';
$marka = '@<div class="test">(.*?)</div>@si';
$getir = file_get_contents($link);

preg_match_all($marka,$getir,$test1);

$test = $test1[0];

echo $test[0]; ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

```
$str = '<img alt="test" title="test" src="/data/brands/test.png">';

$regex = '#src="(.+?)">#';

preg_match($regex,$str,$match);

echo $match[1];

//prints: /data/brands/test.png
```

Comment: Next - it will match `src` from `<script>`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but this code getting only text "/data/brands/test.png". This image changing. Example; site.com/samsung -> image url /data/brands/samsung.png

Comment: @Walter.White you need to describe more clearly what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry for the poor language.
I getting images and brand names on a site. The name of the brand comes up, but the images does not come. Because the images uses a short link. How do I get the full image link.

All I want is to take a picture of each URL.